# ~/.setprompt: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, csh

trying to change directory in csh script. But i am getting following error :

**`~/.setprompt`: No such file or directory**

permission of above file is like that :

-rwxrwxrwx 1 vgangwar 46 Oct  5  2015 /home/vgangwar/.setprompt

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the script where you're calling `cd`, as well as your `.setprompt` script - `.setprompt` might try to call an external program that doesn't exist.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt as these script files are internal files of my company. So i am not allowed to put code in public. But i got the answer. I am doing set noglob in the script which making the problem. this flag prevent wild card pattern matching. Thank you

Comment: The error message is certainly not a result from a `cd`, and `.setprompt` is, to the best of my knowledge, nothing which would have special meaning to csh. Either you have a `precmd` or a `postcmd` defined, or the error comes from a different part of your code. I suggest to run your script with `set echo`.

Comment: @Spartacus if you solved the problem, please post the solution and close the question.

Comment: @user2141046 Thanks for pointing me for posting the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my script, somewhere i am doing `set noglob` which causing the problem.

> noglob - When set prevent filename expansion with wildcard pattern
>   matching

after it , i am trying to change the directory using cd command. That's why i am getting error which is shown in question. It is solved by unsetting the `noglob` (`unset noglob`) variable before changing the directory.